# Infopath form into website

Tags: 2013, web-part, infopath, sharepoint-addin, page-layout

I would like to use the following form in one of my web pages: 
[image]

I have the following problem. I can add things but when I refresh the page everything is deleted. I want the input to be saved once I enter it. I know that this is the normal behavior for a form, but I was wondering if I can achieve what I want using infopath forms. If not could you please suggest something that might do the job ?

Comment: Are you invoking a submit action somewhere before you refresh the page? InfoPath has an easy to add submit button -- add a button control to the page, right click on it, change the "Action" dropdown to "Submit"

Comment: I don't want to submit it as a document with columns. I just want it to remain there but the fields to be customizable.

Comment: You can customize a regular old SharePoint list submission form with InfoPath; meaning that you're not creating and submitting a new document, you're just modifying list data in SharePoint -- some form of data submission is required back to the server in order to save your data, web pages aren't able to remember what was entered into them without some help from a back-end storage mechanism (such as the one SharePoint provides with lists)